# Why artifact.size is 4096

Tags: eclipse, maven, p2

I am creating a P2 repository with a single feature that contains a simple Hello World plugin. I have checked option "Unpack the plugin-archive after the installation".
When I look at artifacts.xml of generated P2 repository, I see following:

```
    <artifact classifier='osgi.bundle' id='helloWorldPlugin' version='1.0.0.201512221406'>
      <properties size='2'>
        <property name='artifact.size' value='4096'/>
        <property name='download.size' value='3610'/>
      </properties>
    </artifact>
```

I can understand that 'download.size' is actually size of archived jar plugin but why is artifact.size '4096'? Shouldn't it be actual size of plugin directory?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the size generation assumes a single file, but the size of a folder in the background is not the size of its contents but the size of its metadata, and 4k is often the smallest file size possible. See also related question [Why is the size of a directory always 4096 bytes in unix?](https://superuser.com/questions/142893/why-is-the-size-of-a-directory-always-4096-bytes-in-unix) in Super User.

Basically, this calculated size is indeed confusing (and quite possibly a bug/missing feature in p2).